# Bigram Collocations for spelling correction ,Python

Tags: python-2.7, replace, nltk, spell-checking, n-gram

I'm building a spelling correction algorithm based on peter norvig's code. Adding my own cases led to an increase in efficiency (since I have no reference text like big.txt and the text consists of mostly non english words).
I noticed that the word "golden" was autocorrected to "garden" (because garden has a higher freq of occurrence in the text). So i've decided to add bigram collocations to the text. This will allow golden to remain golden when it appears in combination with some word with which it usually occurs. I am implementing it and I need some help. here's a piece of the code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokenized) #create bigram pairs in text called tokenized
finder.apply_freq_filter(3) #bigrams which occur less than 3 times will not be considered.
```

The next thing I want to do is add an exception, that if it appears in "finder" then the word isn't supposed to be replaced. How could I use it.?
(if the problem statement doesn't clarify much, I'll edit it on request)